# Rust: почему попадаю на ошибку файла не существует?

Tags: rust

Есть список директорий, идет по нему в цикле и проверяем время модификации в файле (в Linux). Вроде все происходит очень быстро, но периодически славливаю ошибку, что файла не существует, когда он пытается получить по нему modifed. Почему так происходит? Мне казалось все очень быстро должно происходить и попасть на тот момент, когда файл уже перемещен практически не возможно. Есть ли решение более правильное?

Вот кусок, который это делает:

```
  for file in WalkDir::new(_path_hash).into_iter().filter_map(|file| file.ok()) {
        if file.metadata().unwrap().is_file() {
            let time = file.metadata().unwrap().modified();    
}
```

Comment: У меня этот код работает без ошибок. Так что остаётся предположить, что это ваше «практически не возможно» всё-таки случается на практике, проверяйте какие пути появляются в этом цикле

Comment: (ну и ещё непонятно что такое `_path_hash` и с какого перепуга в начале переменной вообще подчёркивание торчит)

Comment: А в переменную сохранить не прокатит?

Comment: _path_hash это остатки от старого кода. Оно тут я так понимаю роли не играет.

Comment: Я попробовал ваш код на Ubuntu 18, SSD. Не было ни одной ошибки. Но из общих соображений вызывать дважды `file.metadata()` немножно расточительно, так как каждое обращение к `metadata` делает системный вызов `fstat64`. ИМХО лучше `file.metadata()` сохранить в переменную.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать использовать функцию metadata() только один раз и сохранить результат в переменную. Затем вы можете проверить, является ли файл файлом, и только после этого получить время модификации. Таким образом вы избежите шанс того, что во время вызова второй функции metadata() - будет ошибка, связанная с переносом или удалением файла

```
for file in WalkDir::new(_path_hash).into_iter().filter_map(|file| file.ok()) {
    let metadata = file.metadata();
    if let Ok(metadata) = metadata {
        if metadata.is_file() {
            let time = metadata.modified();
        }
    } 
}
```